# How to check if an IFile in Java Eclipse Plugin Development really exists?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, plugins

I want to check, if a file exists in an Eclipse workspace.

Therefore I have created an IFile Handle (org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile) via: 
IFolder.getFile("filename"); 
I read, that getFile doesn't check if the file really exists.

So how can I check if it exists? Or is the way general way via IFiles and IFolders wrong for that purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IFile` inherits `IResource#exists()` - that should be what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that this has an inherent race condition which may well be security flaw but at least can cause an exception. It's much better to just assume the file exists, do what you want with it and catch the exception if it doesn't and handle the problem there.

Answer (score 5):

IResource that is the common parent of IFile and IFolder that provides the method exist(). You should use that.

Answer (score 2):

You should call the methods `IResource.refreshLocal(..)` and then `IResource.exists()` on your file object.

For me the `refreshLocal` call was necessary. Otherwise the `exists` would return `false` event if the file exists within the file system.